# Scrapy get on mac vs scrapy get on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I have come across this issue on windows and kept getting unwanted data in my spiders

**Background**
I develop python scrapy spider on my macbook m1 machine and run spiders on my lenovo windows laptop with windows 10
Lately i was getting error i don't know since how long but recently i noticed this difference i am not sure the way around and what is happening cannot find anything on google.

in scrapy shell

```
#MAC M1
fetch('https://www.usherbrooke.ca/recherche/specialistes/details/adolphe.adihou/')
response.xpath('//h3[text()="Mots-clés"]/following-sibling::*').get()

#i get

'<p>Difficulté, apprentissage, didactique, mathématiqu, Formation des maîtres; formation continue, Ressources numériques</p>'

#windows same code
fetch('https://www.usherbrooke.ca/recherche/specialistes/details/adolphe.adihou/')
response.xpath('//h3[text()="Mots-clés"]/following-sibling::*').get()

#return a lot of html
```

Comment: I get the same output on windows `'<p>Difficulté, apprentissage, didactique, mathématiqu, Formation des maîtres; formation continue, Ressources numériques</p>'`. Probably you are running different versions of something. Try create a new virtualenv and use to check the output.

Comment: tried in virutal env but getting the same result i am using anaconda navigator terminal.

Comment: both machines have scrapy 2.5.0 installed any help, thanks in advance